# using function attributes to store results for lazy (potential) processing

Tags: python, function-attributes

I'm doing some collision detection and I would very much like to use the same function in two different contexts. In one context, I would like for it to be something like

```
def detect_collisions(item, others):
    return any(collides(item, other) for other in others)
```

and in another, I would like it to be

```
def get_collisions(item, others):
    return [other for other in others if collides(item, other)]
```

I really hate the idea of writing two functions here. Just keeping their names straight is one turnoff and complicating the interface to the collision detecting is another. so I was thinking:

```
def peek(gen):
    try:
        first = next(gen)
    except StopIteration:
        return False
    else:
        return it.chain((first,), gen)

def get_collisions(item, others):
    get_collisions.all = peek(other for other in others if collides(item, other))
    return get_collisions.all
```

Now when I just want to do a check, I can say:

```
if get_collisions(item, others):
    # aw snap
```

or

```
if not get_collisions(item, others):
    # w00t
```

and in the other context where I actually want to examine them, I can do:

```
if get_collisions(item, others):
    for collision in get_collisions.all:
        # fix it
```

and in both cases, I don't do any more processing than I need to.

I recognize that this is more code than the first two functions but it also has the advantage of:

1. Keeping my interface to the collision detection as a tree with the node at the top level instead of a mid level. This seems simpler.
2. Hooking myself up with a handy peek function. If I use it one other time, then I'm actually writing less code. (In response to YAGNI, if I have it, I will)

So. If you were the proverbial homicidal maniac that knows where I live, would I be expecting a visit from you if I wrote the above code? If so, how would you approach this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Just make `get_collisions` return a generator:

```
def get_collisions(item, others):
    return (other for other in others if collides(item, other))
```

Then, if you want to do a check:

```
for collision in get_collisions(item, others):
    print 'Collision!'
    break
else:
    print 'No collisions!'
```

Comment: that's one thing I thought of but specifically detecting an empty generator is tedious enough to want to have wrapped away in a function like `peek`. I would want to know if it's empty or not and that would involve a flag (ugh!) or reinventing `peek` every time I want to check.

Comment: It would work if I only ever wanted to take action if there were collisions though. +1

Comment: You would just detect the empty case with an `else` clause: i added that to my answer, for reference. A function like `peek` should never be needed in Python: using it is probably a sign that something is wrong.

Comment: good eye. I always ask the dumbest questions on here. I knew that. Thanks for talking me out of it.

Comment: actually, sorry for the accepted psyche out but setting up a loop to throw a break to dodge an else clause on the loop that shouldn't be a loop to do what I want every time I want to do it is just too tedious. It obfuscates the intent of the code.

Comment: Why do you find it tedious? The only addition is a `break`, compared to the other approach's addition of an entire `if` or `for` (plus the helper).

Comment: Also, it may help to stop thinking of `for` as a looping-only construct. `while` is a looping/repetition construct, and so is C's `for`, but Python's use of `for` is more like a map: the idea is not repetition based on a condition, but rather mapping a code block across a collection of items. In this particular case, the idea is to search for and break on the first match, or otherwise, handle the case of no matches being found. This *should* describe the intent of the computation (a collision *search*) more clearly than a relatively opaque boolean flag.

Comment: It's not true that it only add's the `break`. If I only want to make sure it's empty, I have to setup the `for`, `break` and `else` as opposed to simple `if`. It's true that it adds a second statement in the case that I want to actually access the collisions but at least it's a semantically meaningful line as opposed to the convolution I described above.

Comment: with regards to the second point, I've already abstracted away the _actual_ search into a function. That's were the search is actually happening and where the sort of logic you describe is appropriate. The client code _is_ interested in a simple boolean: _did_ you find one or _didn't_ you. It then has the option to get nosy but isn't required too. Also, 'map a block of code across a collection of items' sounds tremendously like 'loop'. And when I think of it like that, I'm more inclined to want to use map or a gen-exp to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to what we were discussing in ["pythonic way to rewrite an assignment in an if statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744382/pythonic-way-to-rewrite-an-assignment-in-an-if-statement/3745343#3745343), but this version only handles one positional or one keyword argument per call so one can always retrieve the actual valued cached (not just whether is a True value in the Pythonian boolean sense or not).

I never really cared for your proposal to accept multiple keywords and have differently named functions depending on whether you wanted all the results put through `any()` or `all()` -- but liked the idea of using keyword arguments which would allow a single function to be used in two or more spots simultaneously. Here's what I ended up with:

```
# can be called with a single unnamed value or a single named value
def cache(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args)+len(kwargs) == 1:
        if args:
            name, value = 'value', args[0]  # default attr name 'value'
        else:
            name, value = kwargs.items()[0]
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('"cache" calls require either a single value argument '
                                  'or a name=value argument identifying an attribute.')
    setattr(cache, name, value)
    return value

# add a sub-function to clear the cache attributes (optional and a little weird)
cache.clear = lambda: cache.func_dict.clear()

# you could then use it either of these two ways
if get_collisions(item, others):
    # no cached value

if cache(collisions=get_collisions(item, others)):
    for collision in cache.collisions:
        # fix them
```

By putting all the ugly details in a separate function, it doesn't affect the code in `get_collisions()` one way or the other, and is also available for use elsewhere.