# Is it possible to check that a list is not empty before grabbing the first element using as few lines as possible in Python?

Tags: python

I keep having to do this operation all over the place in my python code. I'm willing to bet there is an easier (aka one-line) way to do this.

```
results = getResults()
if len(results) > 0:
    result = results[0]
```

I actually don't need "results" anywhere else, and I should only run "getResults" once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be aware also that in the recommended Python style guidelines ( [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), the method should be named `get_results` rather than `getResults`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't specified what `result` should be if `results` is empty, but this is one option (assuming Python 2.6 or greater):

```
result = results[0] if results else None
```

Answer (score 2):

`result = len(results) and results[0] or None`. In case if results[0] is not `0`, or `False`, or any empty container `[], (), '', {}, set(), ...`.

Comment: I think you should make it clearer that this will _only_ work if `results[0]` evaluates to `True`. If `results == range(10)`, say, it will give None.

Comment: @katrielex my comment (the second sentence in the post) doesn't make it clear?

Comment: @khachik: no. _Any_ empty container evaluates to False -- `set()`, `tuple()`, `{}`, `frozenset()`, `0.0`, ... -- it will fail for _any_ of these.

Comment: @khachik: closer =) but still unfortunately not true... a) `0j`, `0L`, `0.0` and b) any class can define a `__nonzero__` method which returns False, in which case instances of that class will evaluate to False. The point is that _anything_ which evaluates to False will cause fail. [Although now I'm just nitpicking; these are at best unlikely to come up.]

Comment: @katrielalex I understand that point, thanks :) also there is `__bool__` in 3.x, there is None... Isn't it obvious since `and` is used?

Comment: @khachik: yes, I guess so. I think the answer is fine, I'm just nitpicking. =)

Answer (score 1):

`next(iter(getResults()), None)` for Python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need `results` anywhere, consider a function that returns just the first result, and use that instead.

```
def getFirstResult():
    results = getResults()
    if len(results) > 0:
        return results[0]
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `getResults()` slightly along these lines:

```
def getResults():
    # ...
    getResults.seq = ... # save results in a func attribute
    return getResults.seq
```

It would allow you to write:

```
results = getResults.seq[0] if getResults() else None
```

Comment: getResults is just an example. It would actually be a different function whenever I use it, and I don't want to have to write a wrapper for every time I use it.

Comment: @Joehillen: This isn't a wrapper, it a permanent change to the function itself that is backwards compatible with previous usage but also allows the one-liner example usage to be used when desired. It's also possible to do it without modifying the function -- see the question [pythonic way to rewrite an assignment in an if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744382/pythonic-way-to-rewrite-an-assignment-in-an-if-statement).